# nautilus not starting ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, libraries, nautilus, ubuntu-18.04

Since a few weeks when I try to start nautilus in Ubuntu 18.04 I get the following message :

```
nautilus: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tracker-2.0/libtracker-data.so.0: undefined symbol: sqlite3_bind_pointer
```

It seems everything else is working fine. I ran `dpkg -l | grep libtracker`:

```
ii  libtracker-sparql-2.0-0:amd64              2.0.3-1ubuntu4                      amd64        metadata database, indexer and search tool - library
```

Then I tryed `sudo apt install --reinstall libtracker-sparql-2.0-0` but it still says the same thing.

Edit: I found [this](https://www.mail-archive.com/desktop-packages@lists.launchpad.net/msg539200.html) when I looked up the error message on google, can it help with anything? In my case the Ubuntu installation is new, not an upgrade from 17.10

Thanks for your help